# warning: cast between incompatible function types

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una envoltura en C++ sobre un código C; dicho código utiliza el patrón *callback*, así que he creado una clase *puntero* cuyo único propósito es *ocultar* un puntero.

En una parte del código tengo que *modelar* un puntero a función, que recibe una instancia de mi clase *puntero*, a un puntero a función que reciba realmente un puntero; un ejemplo mínimo es:

```
struct Data {
};

struct Wrapper {
  Data *ptr = nullptr;
};

void funct( struct Data * ) { }

int main( ) {
  void (*ptr)( Wrapper ) = reinterpret_cast< void(*)( Wrapper ) >( funct );
  ptr( Wrapper( ) );
  return 0;
}
```

<sub>Puede probarse [<kbd>aquí</kbd>](https://tio.run/##VY5BC8IwDIXv/RU5toOB96kn/4NHCV03CrWWLBVh7K9bs06GnhLee/lebErtaG0pE1O2DBdkhFktnVJf5UqYkiMRYXObxAQniDkE2bqafT58D0OOljX8khowMMOilI8Md/RRr4KQ6oFeUUbvFUaw5CTqKJHjm8WJjzWqm7/YWW9lYDphCWQ3V34V5T5ThIP8V8rbDgHHqbTJ9RjZ29Je3YsJZWIIHw)</sub>

Funciona bien, puesto que `Wrapper` cumple con [`Standard Layout Type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType). Sin embargo, el compilador insiste en avisarme de que tenga cuidado con lo que hago (muy educado él):

> cast between incompatible function types from `void (*)(Data*)` to `void (*)(Wrapper)`.

¿ Hay alguna manera **portable** (sin depender del compilador) de eliminar este aviso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `funct` recibe como parámetro un puntero:

```
void funct( struct Data * ) { }
```

Mientras que a la hora de hacer el *cast* le facilitas un objeto por valor:

```
void (*ptr)( Wrapper ) = reinterpret_cast< void(*)( Wrapper ) >( funct );
```

Si cambias el *cast* para que reciba un puntero el *warning* desaparece solo:

```
void (*ptr)( Wrapper* ) = reinterpret_cast< void(*)( Wrapper* ) >( funct );
ptr( new Wrapper( ) );
```

Eso si, nota que el ejemplo tiene fugas de memoria, se entiende que el código original no debería tener este problema (puesto que tendrás que configurar `Wrapper::ptr` en algún sitio)

---

> Gracias, pero no me vale. Se trabaja con instancias de Wrapper en todas partes, no con punteros a instancias...

No veo que eso vaya a ser un problema:

```
Wrapper wrapper;
void (*ptr)( Wrapper* ) = reinterpret_cast< void(*)( Wrapper* ) >( funct );
ptr( & wrapper );
```